# how to convert array of UIImage to array of base64

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, base64

I want convert array of UIImage to array of base64 ?

in swift 5

This code takes a UIImage and returns String (base64)

I want to take a array of UIImage and returns array of String (base64)

Encoding

```py
func ConvertImageToBase64String (img: UIImage) -> String {
    return img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
}
```

Decoding

```py
func ConvertBase64StringToImage (imageBase64String:String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data.init(base64Encoded: imageBase64String, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return image!
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: I want a solution to convert a array of uiimages into a array of base64 string

Comment: Try this

 func imagesToBase64 (images: [UIImage]) -> [String] {
        let result = images.map { (img) in
            img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
        }
        return result as! [String]
    }
    
    func base64ToString (base64Strings:[String]) -> [UIImage?] {
        let result = base64Strings.map { obj in
            return UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: obj)!)
        }
        return result
    }

Comment: don't work
`func base64ToString (base64Strings:[String]) -> [UIImage?] { let result = base64Strings.map { obj in return UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: obj)!) } return result } 
`

Comment: what ??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `base64EncodedString()` after converting `UIImage` instance to `Data` using `pngData()`, i.e.

```
let images = [UIImage]() //your array of images...
let encodedImages = images.compactMap({ $0.pngData()?.base64EncodedString() })
```

Comment: IMO This is a terrible idea and depending on the user device and the number of images the app might crash (out of memory). Btw you should avoid using pngData considering it is a lossless encoding and it generates very large files. jpegData even with a 1.0 quality will result in much smaller data.

Comment: ok .. 
but I won't also convert from [string] to [uiimage] ??